# Any research on right-hand/left-hand based preferences when interacting with an interface?

Tags: motor, hci

My original question is "[Left or right placement of interactive elements on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761057/left-or-right-placement-of-interactive-elements-on-a-web-page)", but only now did I find a place where I think I can find the right people to understand it.

The gist is: is there any natural inclination in right-handed people, when reading a web page, for example, to prefer those interface elements which lead to actions (e.g. "print", "save", "get a link", etc.) to be placed on the right side of the screen and then, to prefer navigational elements (e.g. menus, especially tree-structured category menus) to be placed on the left side, while the preference for content for reading would be in the middle?

That is: navigation (reference stuff) on the left, content (passive perception stuff) in the middle, action elements on the right, all in this manner because of a potential instinct to reach for anything action related with one's right hand.

Is there any research or at least speculation on the subject?

And a follow-up question: if there is such an inclination does it appear to be reverse in left-handed people?

*update:*
- similar question asked here: http://www.quora.com/Are-right-handers-more-likely-to-rest-their-cursor-pointer-on-the-right-hand-side-of-the-screen

Comment: an anecdote: I'm a left-hander (and left-eye dominate) who uses the mouse right-handed and prefers menus and sidebars on the right on the screen.  I expect, however, the file menu to be left-most and have open, close, print, etc.  So expectations from experience might be more important than (or at least compete with) innate preferences.

Comment: your question may also be suitable for [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Jeff Zemla tried there, admins deleted it as either off-topic or too broad,can't remember exactly

Comment: @Xurtio - What do you mean by saying "and prefers menus and sidebars on the right on the screen" - menus and sidebars containing navigational elements or action elements, as described in my question?

Comment: well, like it is here and on Reddit.  Content on left, sidebar on right.  I guess I actually expect menus to be at the top.

Comment: I am also left-handed (and left-eye dominant) but I use computer mice with my right hand, though I wonder if that's more because it's a habit and how I've always used a mouse. Similarly with scissors; as a child I found using scissors with my left hand incredibly frustrating so just eventually grew accustomed to using my right hand and still do so.

Comment: I agree with Xurtio and Phoenix: we are indeed used to do lots of things like right-handed and this convence is more important than our need to have it otherwise. But I appreciate you trying to change that. If there would be considerable amount of webs and software for left-handed people, our left-handed kids could get used to hold the mouse in their left hand. It may be too late for some of us, but this is great idea anyway.

Comment: Buttons on the far right side of the screen for large windows and forms: These all to frequently have no visual cue to guide magnification users across to it. Some magnifications users may not find the button, or may take much longer to find it and as a result the task can take much longer to complete for this user group. There then may be other magnification users that expect the button to be on the right and so always look to the right. So, as a suggestion when placing buttons on the far right add some form of visual cue to guide magnification users across to it.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed some research on handedness and user interfaces but not exactly at the level you seem to be after. Handedness matters for tablet interfaces, hand occlusion is a particular concern there.

Some references: http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00670516/en and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.89.4546

Speculating myself a little bit, I would however be careful when drawing practical conclusions from any putative “natural” handedness-related inclination. Maybe there is such a thing and it could conceivably be measured but you need much more than that to justify any UI decision.

In particular, cultural factors (in a broad sense, including web and platform conventions) could just as well play a big role. The usability literature has always emphasized consistency and the fact that your interface is just going to be one of many interfaces with which users are regularly interacting so when in doubt always try to follow common practice, not necessarily because it is better as such but simply to avoid confusing your users. In any case, there is no reason to worry specifically about “natural” inclinations (as opposed to learned ones).